# Highcharts add new data to series after click

Tags: javascript, highcharts, axis, spline

I'm trying to add a new point (to series data) on spline chart after clicking in the place where I'm clicked on the line. But point click event doesn't return xAxis, yAxis (only in pixels). I decide to calculate the difference between point pixels position and click, but point adds not on the click place. What I'm doing wrong? How to handle this?

My JS

```
var setDragStatus = function (status) {
    document.getElementById('dragstatus').innerHTML = status;
};

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  title: {
    text: 'Spline Drag&Drop'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      turboThreshold: 4,
      minPointLength: 5,
      dragDrop: {
        draggableY: true,
        dragMaxY: 1,
      },
      point: {
        events: {
          click: function (e) {
            let pointPlotX = e.point.plotX
            let pointPlotY = e.point.plotY
            let pointX = e.point.x
            let pointY = e.point.y
            let clickX = e.chartX
            let clickY = e.chartY
            let pointDiffX = clickX / pointPlotX
            let pointDiffY = clickY / pointPlotY
            let newPointX = pointX * pointDiffX
            let newPointY = pointDiffY * pointY
            this.series.addPoint([newPointX, newPointY])
          }
        }
      },

    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    reversed: false,
    showFirstLabel: false,
    showLastLabel: true
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: 'spline top',
      data: [0, 0.3, 0.6, 1],
      type: 'spline'
    }
  ]
}

);
```

Result - https://jsfiddle.net/antiaf/1hfuyjbr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate `x` and `y` values you can use `toValue` Axis method:

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            ...,
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function(e) {
                        let series = this.series,
                            yAxis = series.yAxis,
                            xAxis = series.xAxis,
                            newPointX = xAxis.toValue(e.chartX),
                            newPointY = yAxis.toValue(e.chartY);

                        this.series.addPoint([newPointX, newPointY])
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hg81o4ej/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#toValue